# How to run multiple sql queries through one call in Mysql2 Gem in IRB?

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I am playing around with mysql2 ( and mysql 5) gem and the results and the Enumerable results.

I can run queries such as

```
results = client.query("select now()")
```

And I can also run queries such as

```
results = client.query("select version()")
```

But what I want to do is take it up a notch. In real life, I assume people run multiple queries. So how would I make sure that I can get the version and the time in one shot.

--

Things that I have tried **that do not work**:

```
results = client.query("select version(); select now()")
```

The error I get is:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your Mysql Version for the right syntax to use near 'select now()' at line1
```

Now I understand that I can run the following queries in Mysql Console and get the results back, how would I do the same thing in Mysql2 Gem:

```
select version();select now()
```

How would I do the same with Mysql2 gem in that one command line(or do I need two). I ask because in real life, people usually run multiple queries to get the results in the way they want them in.

Comment: I figured it out. This works similar to Mysql Console. Instead of 
**results = client.query("select now(), select version()")** you do a single select statement.

So to make it work, it would have to be 
**results = client.query("select version(),now()")**

Answer (score 8):

I solved this issue by adding this default query option before connecting to MySQL :

`Mysql2::Client.default_query_options[:connect_flags] |= Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS`

Comment: This just saved me so many hours of headaches! I kept copying the SQL into a client and it ran perfectly! Works 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can just select multiple things at once using a , as in:

```
SELECT VERSION(), NOW();
```

If you need them into one result, then the following will work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(VERSION(), NOW());
```